# How to get docs for non-currentUsers in Firebase and Vue

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to built a chat app with Vue, Firebase Firestore and Firebase authentication. After registering a user, logging in, and submitting a message, I am using the getMessage function below to retrieve the messages from a collection assigned to a doc for the currently logged-in user.

```
const messages = ref([])

const getMessages = () => {
firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        messages.value = []
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          var msg = doc.data();
          msg.id = doc.id;
          messages.value.push(msg)
        })
      }) 
    },
```

However, I have multiple registered users and am wanting to retrieve messages for all the users, not just the currentUser. How can I set up the above firestore collection method chain to retrieve messages for all of the registered users, not just currentUser?

Comment: You can use a [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query but are you sure you want anyone to read messages of all users or are you restricting it to some admin only?

Comment: Yes because my messenger app will be configured so as to display currentUser messages on the right and non-currentUser messages on the left, similar to Whatsapp or Signal. Therefore I will need access to all of the messages while logged into the currentUser.

Comment: The answer below should do. But what if a User A has messages with User B. User C can read those as well for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query here that'll fetch messages from all users as per your use case.

```
const messages = ref([])

const getMessages = () => {
  firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("messages").orderBy('timestamp')
    .onSnapshot(snap => {
      const messages = snap.docs.map((doc) => ({
        messageId: doc.id,
        userId: doc.parent.parent.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }))

      messages.value = messages
    })
}
```

Do make sure your security allow users to add message to their sub-collection only but let everyone read them. For example,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{userId=**}/messages/{messageId} {
      allow read: if request.auth == userId; 
    }
 
    match /users/{userId}/messages/{messageId} { 
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups) for more information about security rules.

Comment: Thanks. I am implementing that now. For the security instruction you provided, is that handled under rules in Cloud Firestore? If so, what would that rule change look like?

Comment: Also, when I add the above function you indicated, I get the following error: ```The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC index for collection messages and field timestamp```

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 that error should also contain a link that you can use to create the index?

Comment: Ah yes, I clicked the link. It's prompting me to add exemptions under the index tab in Cloud Firestore

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 just follow the link and the instructions. Once the index is created the query should work. Also I've added an example of security rules. Again this allows everyone to read messages of all users so do ensure that it's your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the above rule change, as you indicated. However, I'm getting the following error: ```FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.```

Comment: @JS_is_awesome18 can you try `match /{userId=**}/messages/{messageId}` ? instead of current path

Comment: Oh! That worked. I changed out the current path in the rules for the new line you provided. Works! Thank you!